# Server side rendered templates for AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I am building a complex web page, that has many users/groups/permissions where user can see all/some/none of the object of specific type according to the ACL (using [Symfony2](https://symfony.com/) and [Symfony2 ACL](https://github.com/symfony/security-acl)).

What am I dealing with now is that I don't want to show every UI element in the frontend and just throw 403 error if user does something that he has not permission for. Hidding elements that the user has no permission to see would be better for UX.

It is like if I show a product info page for the user, I don't want to show the EDIT/DELETE buttons, if user does not have permission for doing that on this product or all products (class scope permission).

With [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and server side rendered templates it would be easy as adding bunch of permission checks in template

```
{% if is_granted('EDIT', product) %}
    <button>Edit product</buttom>
{% endif %}
```

But how to handle this in clientside with [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/)?

What I was thinking is the following:

1. Create a controller method that serves Twig templates rendered server side for AngularJs. This takes a parameter of `id` identifying the object, which the user must have permissions on in order to see the EDIT/DELETE buttons rendered in the template ([Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and `is_granted()` handles this serverside)
2. User ask to view a specific product `/product/1`. The router `templateUrl` would be `/templates/product/view.html?object_id=1`, where `object_id` identify the object, that should be used while rendering templates serverside to grant or deny rendering ui elements.
3. The product JSON is then fetched and put in the template, which has already been rendered serverside, and has some Angular `{{ }}` waiting for product data to be placed in.

Are there any similar cases solved using other serverside technologies that you are familiar with and can be taken as an example to lead me on my way to success?

Answer (score 0):

In our project client side Angular code is enough.

- **Back end wont ever send any data to front end user have no permission to view/access. (403)**
- Front end present login page to user with witch user can authenticate. Front end then send provided credentials to Back end, which is responsible for actual checks.
- Back end will provide Front end with user role/access right/privileges. If those are more complex dedicated API endpoints will be provided. (Fe: Can user access this? Be: No. Fe: that? Be: Yes, but not delete. etc.)
- Front end will use if's on data returned from Back end to conditionally render UI parts.

Do note that I use back end and front end, as described technique is framework agnostic and will work with pretty much any.

For Angular we created `CurrentUser` service that had `is('role_name')` that would return true if user had assigned role, false otherwise. ng-if or plain old if(), then where used to conditionally render html tags/data.

Comment: I need to check users permission on specifict object for specific action (VIEW/CREATE/EDIT/DELETE). Making API call to check this on every object would not be efficient I think.

Comment: Can You extend API so that it sends ACL alongside data, every time front end request it? Then You need some service that decode that acl data, but on UI its still one if per action.

Comment: @nn4n4s You should not send data that loged user can not `VIEW` If there are some aggregate values computed from it, do it on back end. Ultimatly user can hit F12, access dev tools, and see **whole** network traffic. So do not sent such data at all.